# "Stitching" multiple 2d Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, simplex

EDIT (rephrased question):
How would I use the provided smoothstep function to create a gradual transition between adjacent 2d arrays? Each array is the same size and contain values ranging between 0 and 1, having a smooth transition from edge to edge via simplex noise. As a result I'm wanting the difference between adjacent array values to be at maxiumum 0.04

```
function smoothstep (min, max, value) {
    var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (value-min)/(max-min)));
    return x*x*(3 - 2*x);
};
```

---

I have 6 2d arrays containing values between 0 and 1 to represent heights on the face of a sphere. To iterate through all values of the arrays i have this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cube.faces.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < cube.faces[i].heightMap.length; x++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < cube.faces[i].heightMap.length; z++) {
            if (x == 0 || x == cube.faces[i].heightMap.length - 1 || z == 0 || z == cube.faces[i].heightMap.length - 1) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        if (x == 0) {
                            //match left of face 1 to top of face 4
                        } else if (z == 0) {
                            //match top of face 1 to top of face 6
                        } else if (z == cube.faces[i].heightMap.length - 1) {
                            //match bottom of face 1 to top of face 5
                        } else {
                            //match right of face 1 to top of face 3
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (x == 0) {
                            //match left of face 2 to bottom of face 3
                        } else if (z == 0) {
                            //match top of face 2 to bottom of face 6
                        } else if (z == cube.faces[i].heightMap.length - 1) {
                            //match bottom of face 2 to bottom of face 5
                        } else {
                            //match right of face 2 to bottom of face 4
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (x == 0) {
                            //match left of face 3 to right of face 5
                        } else if (z == 0) {
                            //~~match top of face 3 to right of face 1~~
                        } else if (z == cube.faces[i].heightMap.length - 1) {
                            //~~match bottom of face 3 to left of face 2~~
                        } else {
                            //match right of face 3 to left of face 6
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (x == 0) {
                            //match left of face 4 to right of face 6
                        } else if (z == 0) {
                            //~~match top of face 4 to left of face 1~~
                        } else if (z == cube.faces[i].heightMap.length - 1) {
                            //~~match bottom of face 4 to right of face 2~~
                        } else {
                            //match right of face 4 to left of face 5
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm having some trouble getting the faces to match up. Looking into this i have found a function called "smoothstep" which seems to be exactly what i need. i don't know how to implement it, i have yet to find an explanation that is useful to me.

```
function smoothstep(min, max, value) {
    var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (value - min) / (max - min)));
    return x * x * (3 - 2 * x);
};
```

The following page is where i learned of this method, but i can not make sense of what is trying to be said. if anyone has the time could you explain how i may implement this into my situation? [Link to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433122/how-can-you-stitch-multiple-heightmaps-together-to-remove-seems)

Comment: Example inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs, explain what's going wrong. Don't just post a chunk of code and say it's not working.

Comment: the question is how to implement the smoothstep algorithm to two 2d arrays containing values between 0 and 1 so that their currently not seamless edges become seamless. if you really need an example i can give one, but any input that meets these parameters will do.

Comment: So what's the desired result? What does it do? Do you have a reference? You've already provided an implementation, so what's the problem? Inputs and outputs please.

Comment: inputs are vast but always a 2d array containing values between 0 and 1. any 2d array between 0 and 1. all arrays are equal in size. expected output is that the values on adjacent arrays edges are roughly equal without effecting the slope throughout the original arrays. output i'm getting now is none because i'm asking to have this smoothstep explained so i can begin working on this. my research on this topic leads me to believe smoothstep is the proper algorithm however i am having trouble grasping it which is the entirety of my question. maybe you misunderstand what is being asked.

Comment: At the very least you need to include some more relevant tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113860/discussion-between-johnathan-ralls-and-fizzytea).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what operations are allowed here. Are you filling in gaps between heightmaps (e.g.: by inserting fillers) or are you modifying the existing heightmaps? If you're modifying the existing arrays, how much modification is allowed? Meanwhile, the smoothstep "algorithm" as presented here appears to be just a cubic function that maps [0,1] to [0,1] in kind of a [gentle S-shape](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x^2*%283-2*x%29,+x%3D0..1).

Comment: I would like to modify the existing heightmaps and have no adjacent values differ greater than 0.04. From what I've read so far, smoothstep is a 'step' in the right direction but if you know something better that would be wonderful!

Comment: what i have so far is to find the average of the two adjacent edges of the arrays, and then from the edge inwards on each array modify values 25 columns (or rows) inward to cover the greatest possible difference of edges (difference of 1 / tolerance of 0.04).

Comment: @JohnathanRalls Surely, though, there must be some limit to or guidelines for how much you're able to modify the existing heightmaps. Otherwise, you could just set all entries to zero and call it a day.

Comment: I see what you mean. I would like to keep all values as close to their original values as possible, but is not meaning that they cannot be change drastically to fit the previous restrictions. An all zero height map is not useful, but I guess because I didn't say that does not make it implied.

Comment: @JohnathanRalls Ok. Also, within each individual heightmap, are there adjacent values with differences greater than 0.04 that also need to be smoothed out?

Comment: No they are all good

Comment: I tried to implement the solution to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433122/how-can-you-stitch-multiple-heightmaps-together-to-remove-seams) you linked to but I'm not sure if the [result](https://jsfiddle.net/ztejyvy1/) is what you are trying to achieve (the heightmaps are stitched together and the seams are removed but you can still see where the maps have been stitched together because the regions at the edges of the map are partially mirrored).

Comment: If there were a way to add a bit of variance to the seams i think this would work out, as each heightmap would be unique so the seams would not repeat

Comment: The last JSFiddle had a small mistake (fixed version here: https://jsfiddle.net/ztejyvy1/1/). @JohnathanRalls: I have spent some time trying to figure out how to add variance - but so far I didn't come up with a successful idea. If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution, at the moment i've got cascaded for loops within a switch to match up with each side and intend to set the edges to the average of each side and work from there. a lot of cases to account for with this!

Answer (score 0):

RE: Smoothstep, I recreated the function in Python's IDLE interpreter real quick so that I could plug values into it and get instant results, and as near as I can tell, all it does is stretch your min value to 0, your max value to 1, then normalizes the value parameter accordingly.

For example, if you provide parameters `(0.2, 0.4, 0.3)`   0.3 is halfway between 0.2 and 0.4, so the function will normalize the value to approx 0.5

Are you just trying to create a solid gradient of numbers with the 50 array rows/columns that intersect Edge A and Edge B?

If so, I don't know if smoothstep is the way to go.

Regardless, for something like this, I would get physical and bust out a sheet of paper and draw out something like this with the array id in the middle and label the edges  (Assuming a dice face pattern in the example below):

```
        |--A--|
        D  3  B
        |--C--|

        |--A--|
        D  1  B
        |--C--|

|--A--| |--A--| |--A--|
D  2  B D  4  B D  5  B
|--C--| |--C--| |--C--|

        |--A--|
        D  6  B
        |--C--|
```

Then fold it up in your mind (or cut it out and physically fold up the cube) to find the edge pairs and draw arrows indicating the direction inward into the face from the edge.   (I like to use N(orth), E(ast), S(outh), W(est) to visualize which direction to head from the edge.

Heading direction:

```
N = Same columnID, Start at max RowID and decrement  (going north)
E = Same rowID, Start at min ColumnID and increment  (going east)
S = Same columnID, Start at min RowID and increment  (going south)
W = Same rowID, Start at max ColumnID and decrement  (going west)
```

You would end up with a list of something like  `var list = [1,B,W,, 5,A,S,], [4,B,W,, 5,D,E,]...etc...]`  (extra commas are intentional, representing a blank space in the list well fill in next)

Now with that list built out you would grab the value, 25 rows or columns in from the edge in whatever direction you noted for each array, plug it into your list in the blank spaces and you'll have the absolute min and a max values for your gradient. e.g. `var list = [[1,B,W,0.3, 5,A,S,0.7],...etc...]`

Then if it's a solid gradient, you'd just do some easy math `step_value = Math.abs(list[n][3] - list[n][7])/50`   then increment or decrement from your starting value for each edge, in the appropriate direction, depending on whether it's the min or the max.

If it's more complicated than a straight gradient between 2D array edges, I apologize, but will probably need a better visualization of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you wanting my data values, or will seeing my entire project be more satisfactory? They are a range of values from 0 to 1, adjacent values differing no more than 0.04 giving a gradual rolling terrain appearance.

Comment: I guess I'm just not entirely clear on if the 25 values that form the edge are important, or if you just want to take two values, 25 in from either edge, and draw a straight gradient between them?

Comment: I got 25 from taking 1/0.04 to ensure worst case scenario would be accounted for, but again I'm not sure if I'm on the right track at all for this.

Comment: So you could actually go 13 in from each edge (26 total) to say under your .04 variation worst case scenario cap.   With a straight gradient on all edges, the corners of the 'cube' will look a little goofy.  Not sure what the best way around that would be, though.

Comment: ah, that's right! from there would i just average the heights on either side, and then keep stepping inward from each edge changing values to within the tolerance (0.04)? Because that would put me back at finding the particular algorithm to use to give a smooth transition from the average to the point where the difference in within the tolerance, in this case at max 13 steps.

Answer (score 0):

To try and explain smoothstep. You first start with a linear interpolation between the two values, and then modify it by using a cubic function.

[image: Smoothstep interpolation]

The diagram shows linear interpolation between 0 and 1 in green, and the smoothed version in red. I've clamped the values for x outside the range, but you can also see the continuation of the cubic in black.

In the function

```
function smoothstep(min, max, value) {
    var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (value - min) / (max - min)));
    return x * x * (3 - 2 * x);
};
```

The function will always return a value between 0 and 1. If value < min it returns 0 and if value > max it returns 1. If value is between min and max you get an interpolated value.

Mathematically it is a piece of the cubic 3 x^2 - 2 x^3.

---

My first instinct would be to apply a [Gaussian blurring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) along each edge.

Comment: i'm not sure how you would implement gaussian blurring within a tolerance, as the values on the edges of the arrays will be modified the most and being as close to the original value as possible the further you go towards their center.